# Accessing an API with multiple cubes using 'for' loop or 'lapply' in R, with pagination, and saving to multiple dataframes

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, cubes

Thank you in advance for anyone who takes the time to help with this!

I'm trying to download all data from https://municipaldata.treasury.gov.za/docs#general and save each cube as an individual dataframes. I'm using R for this.

I've been trying to use `lappy` and `for` loops to download all cubes and pages without success.

So there are three aspects that I'm trying to address:

1. Download all 21 cubes (see the end for the structure of the URL)
2. Save all items from each cube as a separate dataframe
3. Download all items from all pages (there's pagination and a limit of 10 000 items per a page)

For the cubes (1), I don't know how to  don't know how to use `lapply` or `for` loops to save multiple dataframes as outputs (2).

I've figured out the pagination part (3) using a `for` loop (any help applying it to `lapply` would be appreciated), but the solution requires me to run the code separately for each cube.

Example, for the cube '*repmaint*', to get all the data using a `for` loop:

```
# set df
df_repmaint <-  data.frame()

# get the number of items to determine the number of pages
url_repmaint <- fromJSON("https://municipaldata.treasury.gov.za/api/cubes/repmaint/facts")

# as there are max 10 000 items per a page, calculate the number of pages
perpage <- ceiling(url_repmaint$total_fact_count / 10000)

# set up loop
for(i in 1:perpage){
  
# get cube data for each page
  repmaint_page <- fromJSON(paste0("https://municipaldata.treasury.gov.za/api/cubes/repmaint/facts?page=",i))
  
# just to show it's working
  message("Retrieving page ", i)
  
# save output into a single dataframe
  df_repmaint <- rbind(df_repmaint,repmaint_page$data)
}
```

And then, I would want to save the output as separate dataframes.

As you can see, definitely out of my depth but trying to learn!

On the structure of the url:

The url to access data from cubes is structured as follows: [https://municipaldata.treasury.gov.za/api/cubes/*'cube](https://municipaldata.treasury.gov.za/api/cubes/*%27cube) name'*/facts?page=*'page number'*

for which I can easily create a list of cube names using the following formula

```
# extract JSON from URL
JSON_datasets<- fromJSON("https://municipaldata.treasury.gov.za/api/cubes")

# turn into dataframe
df_datasets <- as.data.frame(JSON_datasets[[2]])  

# save as a list of each individual url
urls <-
  sprintf("https://municipaldata.treasury.gov.za/api/cubes/%s/facts",
          df_datasets$name)

# check list
urls
```